# Protecting TCP server

Tags: tcp, network-programming

I've been thinking about possible attacks on my server software recently and am looking for information on how others have solved this problem.

Let's say I have a server listening on port 1000 for connections.  I can write code to connect to this port and start sending bad data very easily.  What is an effective way to protect against this?  If you look at a Wireshark capture the first 3 packets are the TCP 3-way handshake; everything after that is application data.

Validating incoming data seems to make sense, but then I started thinking about World of Warcraft.  I assume there is some kind of mechanism in place to make sure that what's connecting to a WOW server is indeed a WOW client (or maybe there's not).

Thanks for any information on this topic.

Comment: This is really a multi-part question; a lot of this can be handled outside of your application, things like rate limiting and malformed TCP traffic are best dealt with by a firewall or other network appliance (as they tend to be dangerous outside on a level outside of what your application cares about). From your perspective, the best things you can do are ensure you're sanitizing and validating input to your server.

Answer (score 3):

Validating incoming data is the answer. If your program detects invalid data, disconnect the client.

Low-level TCP and DOS/DDOS attacks are better handled at the system level by a dedicated firewall application or device. They are specifically designed to detect and handle this sort of thing.